# htmlParse loop retry value when parse fails

Tags: xml, r, loops, web-scraping

How can I retry my value in a loop?

I am parsing html and every once in awhile the parse will not grab the whole table causing an error later in the code when I try to bind rows from another data frame. I have another variable that has the actual number of rows that I can check against.

My thought was

```
for(thisURL in URLs){

  for (l in 1:10) {
    b <- htmlParse(thisURL)
    tableNode <- xpathSApply(batting, '//*[@id="logs"]')[[1]]
    data <- readHTMLTable(tableNode, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    gid <- xpathSApply(b, '//*[contains(@id, "logs.")]/td[12]/span/@id')

    if length(data[[1]]) == length(gid) then exit this loop continue with the original loop else retry the htmlParse

  }

  remainder of first for loop

}
```

I'm new with R and I'm not sure how to exit the loop if the lengths equal.  I'm pretty sure if I use next, it will go to the next value in the 1:10 loop not the first loop.  If there is a better way, please suggest it.  Thanks for any help!!

Comment: What is "this" loop and what is "original" loop?

Comment: "this" loop is the 1:10 loop and the "original" loop is the thisURL in URLs loop

Comment: If you're ultimately trying to build a data frame from extracted data on pages from a list of URLs, there's a _much_ better way to do it than two `for` loops.

Comment: @hrbrmstr what do you need from me to do it the much better way?

Comment: having ` dput(URLs)` would help answer

Comment: http://espn.go.com/mlb/player/gamelog/_/id/31007/year/2014/jason-kipnis
http://espn.go.com/mlb/player/gamelog/_/id/31007/year/2013/jason-kipnis
http://espn.go.com/mlb/player/gamelog/_/id/31007/year/2012/jason-kipnis
http://espn.go.com/mlb/player/gamelog/_/id/31007/year/2011/jason-kipnis
http://espn.go.com/mlb/player/gamelog/_/id/30043/year/2014/michael-brantley
http://espn.go.com/mlb/player/gamelog/_/id/30043/year/2013/michael-brantley
http://espn.go.com/mlb/player/gamelog/_/id/30043/year/2012/michael-brantley
http://espn.go.com/mlb/player/gamelog/_/id/30043/year/2011/michael-brantley

Comment: You really might want to read the Terms of Use on sites you scrape http://disneytermsofuse.com/english/ before, then, deliberately violating them.

Comment: I couldn't find any terms of use for Elias Sports Bureau.  I've googled and nothing comes up at all.  I thought I was ok.  If you look at the bottom of the pages I listed, it says "Data provided by Elias Sports Bureau".  I DID read ESPN's terms of Use before I started and it states that any content provided by third parties is privy to their terms of use.  Since I couldn't find a terms of use for Elias on google or their website, I thought I was ok, I'm apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell what the index `l` is doing in the the 1:10 loop.  It seems like you want a `while` statement instead though.  Something like this maybe?

```
for(thisURL in URLs){

  # These assignments get the while loop started
  data <- NULL 
  gid <- NA

  # Number of retries and initial l
  l.max <- 10  
  l <- 0

  # This will run as long as the lengths are unequal for at most l.max times 
  while (length(data[[1]]) != length(gid) & l < l.max) {
    l <- l+1
    tableNode <- xpathSApply(batting, '//*[@id="logs"]')[[1]]
    data <- readHTMLTable(tableNode, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    gid <- xpathSApply(b, '//*[contains(@id, "logs.")]/td[12]/span/@id')
  }

  remainder of first for loop

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see it in there.  It's part of a progress bar.   If I do a while, won't the while stop if it does equal?

Comment: Don't you want the loop to stop if the two are equal? My suggested code would start your 1:10 loop but stop before 10 if data and grid have the same length.

Comment: I think my post of what I thought should work confused you.  I used to loop for the purpose of retrying 10 times.  I probably explained it backwards as well, as I want the code to be executed as long they equal, so
      while (length(data[[1]]) == length(gid))
is what it should probably be.
What I would like to happen is if they do not equal, that it would just retry the current url until the do equal and proceed.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: I edited my answer a bit so hopefully it is more clear.  The while loop will start and run until the lengths are equal.  Then it stops and the rest of the url loop will continue.  The l.max part is not necessary if you know that eventually the two will have equal lengths.  You want this if the two never being equal is a possibility (in that case the while loop would never terminate).